# Determine $"a"$ for which the system has no solutions, infinitely many solutions, or has one solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the system $$x+y+5z=-7$$ $$-2x-y-2z=5$$ $$x+2y+(a^2+9)z=4a-8 $$

- Determine the value of $a$ (if any) for which the system has no solutions.
- Determine the value of $a$ (if any) for which the system has exactly one solution.
- Determine the value of $a$ (if any) for which the system has infinitely many solutions

I created a matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 & 5 & \Big\vert & -7\\ -2 & -1 & -2 & \Big\vert& 5\\1 & 2 & a^2+9 & \Big\vert& 4a-8\end{pmatrix}$$
I have no idea what to do after though.

Comment: Use row-reduction to reduce your matrix to echelon form. Then check consistency based on he value of $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the augmented matrix $$[A \vert b]=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 5 & -7\\-2 & -1 & -2 & 5\\1 & 2 & a^2+9 & 4a-8\end{pmatrix}$$ which is equivalent to $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 5 & -7\\0 & 1 & 8 & -9\\0 & 1 & a^2+4 & 4a-1\end{pmatrix}$$ which is equivalent to $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 5 & -7\\0 & 1 & 8 & -9\\0 & 0 & a^2-2^2 & 4(a+2)\end{pmatrix}$$

which is equivalent to $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -3 & 2\\0 & 1 & 8 & -9\\0 & 0 & a^2-2^2 & 4(a+2)\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you conclude now?

**Added**:

- If $a=2$, then $\text{rank}(A)=2$ while $\text{rank}([A \vert b])=3$

This case, the system has no solution

- If $a=-2$, then $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}([A \vert b])=2$

This case, the system has infinite number of solutions

- If $a \neq \pm2$, then $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}([A \vert b])=3$

This case, the system has a unique solution