# What are the values of "a" for which the system has: a. one solution b. No solution c. infinite solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following system of linear equations: 
\begin{align}
x + y + z &= 2 \\
2x + 3y + 2z &= 5 \\ 
2x + 3y + ((a^2) − 5)z &= a + 1 
\end{align}

I started by doing the augmented matrix. I don't understand how I can find the solutions. I know that one solution is only one point, infinite is anything and zero is nothing. what are the calculations to arrive at the answer? thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It's great that you described what you'd tried so far, although I cou;dn't really follow it; filling in a few more details (click "edit" just below your question to change it) might help a lot. Also, to make things more readable, we mark up formulas with "MathJax", which you can learn about here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. The first 20 lines or so will tell you most of what you need to know. I'll edit your question a little to show you how it goes.

Comment: Aside from the difference in coefficients, this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2944003/265466 and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Multiplying your first equation by $-2$ and adding to the second we get $$y=1$$. Doing the same with the first one  and adding to the third equation we get

$$z\left(a^2-7\right)=a-4$$
Can you finish?
Sorry for my typo!
So we get
If $a\pm\sqrt{7}$ so no Solutions.
If $a\neq \pm\sqrt{7}$ then we get
$z=\frac{a-4}{a^2-7}$

Comment: I understand the calculations and the way you did it, but how could I find the one solution, zero solution and infinite solutions. It's really that part that I'm confused

Comment: Distinguish the cases $a^2-7=0$ and $a^2-7\neq 0$

Comment: I found that when a^{2} - 7 = 0, the answer is impossible, so that means that when it's equal to zere it's the zero solution. But if the number is not zero, does that mean that it's an infinite amount of solution?

Comment: Try giving names to things. In the sentence "But if the number is not zero, does that mean that **it's** an infinite amount of solution?" what does "it" refer to? By rules of English, it should refer to the number in the first clause, but not every nonzero number is infinite. (Indeed, **no** number is infinite!).

Comment: I totally understood the no solution. What I also understood is that for an infinite amount of solutions, the matrix needs to have a line where it's all zero. So I chose the last line where there is the "a" and I found that $0=\frac{a-4}{a^2-7}-1$. I did a quadratic formula and arrived with an answer: $a=\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}$ and $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$. Are those a good answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

It sounds as if you subtracted the second equation from the third to get
$$
(a^2 - 7) z = a-4.
$$
Dividing through by $a^2 - 7$ tells you a value for $z$...except in a few special cases. Can you identify these cases? What do they tell you? Try plugging in the particular value for $a$ and seeing what equations you end up with.